# category.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (category.js:9)

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm trying to create an e-shop and I want different categories to show up when a div is active.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const tab_switchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switcher]');

    for (let i = 0; i < tab_switchers.length; i++) {
        const tab_switcher = tab_switchers[i];
        const page_id = tab_switcher.dataset.tab;

        tab_switcher.addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.querySelector('.sidenav .tabs .tab.is-active').classList.remove('is-active');
            tab_switcher.parentNode.classList.add('is-active');

            SwitchPage(page_id);
        });
    }
}

function SwitchPage (page_id) {
    const current_page = document.querySelector('.pages .page.is-active');
    current_page.classList.remove('is-active')

    const next_page = document.querySelector(`.pages .page[data-page="${page_id}]`);
    next_page.classList.add('is-active');
}
```

HTML: ```

```
<ul class="tabs"></ul>
    <li class="tab is-active">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="1">Dell</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="2">Apple</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="3">HP</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="4">Toshiba</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="5">Lenovo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="6">Acer</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="7">Asus</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="8">Microsoft</a>
    </li>
```

```

I don't know what else to do or look for, I'm still in javascript but I followed an exact tutorial and worked for him

Comment: can you post completed html?

Comment: Hi that is tthe full html for that section

Answer (score 0):

many mistake from your example code: `<ul class="tabs"></ul>` is closed not including li, `onst next_page = document.querySelector(`.pages .page[data-page="${page_id}]`);` quote for page_id is not properly closed.

Here is the working snippet from your example code.

```js
const tab_switchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-switcher]');

  for (let i = 0; i < tab_switchers.length; i++) {
        const tab_switcher = tab_switchers[i];
        const page_id = tab_switcher.dataset.tab;
        
        tab_switcher.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            document.querySelector('.tabs .tab.is-active').classList.remove('is-active');
            
            tab_switcher.parentNode.classList.add('is-active');

            SwitchPage(page_id);
        });
    }


function SwitchPage (page_id) {
    const current_page = document.querySelector('.pages .page.is-active');
   
    current_page.classList.remove('is-active')

    const next_page = document.querySelector(`.pages .page[data-page="${page_id}"]`);
     
    next_page.classList.add('is-active');
}
```

```css
ul.tabs {
display:flex;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

ul.tabs li {
list-style:none;
margin-right:10px;
cursor:pointer;
}



ul.tabs li.is-active {
text-decoration:underline;
}
.pages .page {
display:none;
}

.pages .page.is-active {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab is-active">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="1">Dell</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="2">Apple</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tab">
        <a data-switcher data-tab="3">HP</a>
    </li>
    
</ul>
<div class="pages">
  <div class="page is-active" data-page="1">Page Dell</div>
  <div class="page" data-page="2">Page Apple</div>
  <div class="page" data-page="3">Page HP</div>
</div>
```